# Good, free software for candlestick charting (using CSV or text input file)

Tags: gratis, microsoft-excel, charts, csv

I am looking for Desktop software which takes Daily Open/Close/High/Low (and possibly Volume) input as csv or any text format.

I already have Excel but I found several shortcomings with Excel

- If my chart is rather long or wide, then Excel does not provide me with a way to anchor the axes while scrolling. So when I looking at a particular candlestick, I am unable to see the axes & their marking labels. Excel allows you to freeze/anchor a row or a column, but doesn't allow you to do this with axes in a chart.
- Drawing something on top of an Excel chart is rather painful. The number of steps involved in just drawing a line on a chart makes it quite cumbersome.
- If you add volume to Excel Candlestick - it then changes the y-axis scaling in such a way, that either the candles become uninterpretable. I would prefer the volume chart be below the candle chart with it's own y-axis. I have now gone around to creating 2 different charts & aligning their X-axis dates with each other.

Is there any free software which satisfies my requirements? I am not looking for the software to download it's own data from the exchange but take input from a flat file. Volume plotting is not necessary but a bonus. Likewise, if the software can identify patterns in the chart that would be a bonus but is not a must.

Comment: Consider using [GNU plot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `plotly` library for `R` (all FOSS) supports candlestick charts.  See https://plot.ly/r/candlestick-charts/ for documentation and an example.

Comment: I am fine calling functions from a library to make the chart, but having to call functions to make annotations & draw lines would be even more cumbersome than using excel. Excel makes candlesticks just fine - it's the other things I mentioned which made me look for alternatives.